# Where do Internal testers download Google Play Android apps?

Tags: android, google-play, publishing

I thought I need just this link `https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.here.myapp.name` to download an app from Play Store, but when I click on it from tester account (which in tester list) I can only see [image]

Comment: If your release status is  In review, that means they are still reviewing your app to make sure it's compliant.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

The link of testing will be https://play.google.com/apps/testing/packagename and you can find that in Alpha/Beta publish tab.

**https://play.google.com/apps/publish --> Select app --> Release Management --> App Release --> Alpha/Beta --> Manage -->  Opt-in URL (URL for testing)**

**Updated to add tester (Close test)**

Add testers

1. On the left menu, select Settings Settings > Manage testers > Create
   a list.
2. Type a name to identify your list of testers. You can use the same list for future tests on any of your apps.
3. Add email addresses and create list.
4. On the left menu,select Release management > App releases.
5. Next, to the closed track, select Manage.
6. Next to "Choose a testing method," select Closed Testing.
7. In the "Users" section, check the box next to the list you want to use.
8. List of will be notified and selected user can accept the invitation and test the app.

Comment: It helps. Thank Jay

Comment: Is there any way for testers to see application in google play without URL?

Comment: @solaza, No there is no such option.

Comment: @Jay is there any closed release is which you can select emails of people who can access application and see it in Google Play?

Comment: @Jay I know how add them but don't know if and where they can see it on google play without URL.

Comment: @solaza, Without accepting the invitation they won't be able to test the app.

Comment: @Jay I know but my question was if there is any option for you to select emails and only that people can see it on Google Play without URL.

Comment: @Jay , sorry , but I have checked and nothing is being sent when I create the internal tester list and upload new apk and therefore create new release. I am completely confused how to get the internal closed testing release to the people via email if they do not receive any email at all.

Comment: Sorry @HX_unbanned, Copy the "Opt-in URL" to share with your close tester user and only added email address can test the application from Opt-in URL

Comment: @Jay , thanks , that is what I have understood so far. But I am now trying to understand when this Opt-in URL will be provided and how. Does URL show up once app is published? Does it show up once app is Released? Does it show up same in all tracks? Google documentation is one big pile of crap and is not giving any sense of workflow...

Comment: @HX_unbanned, you find the Opt-in URL from steps suggested in answer.
Opt-in URL is available when publish for alpha or beta build for testing.

Comment: @Jay , yes , so that is my point - I have published (the status for the App still is in 'Pending publish / Update in progress') the alpha build and the Opt-In URL is still empty.

Comment: This answer is for alpha and beta channels whereas the question is for internal testers. Once you have spent hours to publish your internal testing release: is there any way whatsoever to actually test it? Or do you have to create yet another alpha channel release to actually test the app?

Comment: There seems to be a confusing differentiation between "launch" and publish (not sure what exactly what words are used in English). After you review and approve the app, there is a message inside the internal test interface that says the app is approved. Yet there might be no link because the app is not published. Then go to the dashboard (or overview or however it is translated to your language - link on the left menu above Statistics). At the top of the dashboard the app logo and name are visible, and right there it might say that the app is pending for publish, even if you were not informed

Comment: Thank you @RobinManoli, this was indeed the case and it's very confusing.

Comment: The UI might have changed, now it's under the "Testers" tab. If you go to Testing > Internal Testing > Testers > Scroll to "How testers join your test" > there is a Copy Link button. (April 2022)

Comment: This comment might get me expelled from the internet* and such, but WHY is Android development so painful? This and another 100,000 little papercuts only become evident to me once doing full time cross-platform with Flutter. TestFlight? All your testers get a "new version notification". Android? Let me copy and paste this link for everyone... Did you try to work on a platform-specific plugin? LOL

Answer (score 58):

### For the new Google Play Console version

1. Open your app → Release → Testing → Internal testing
2. Tap on **Testers** → Scroll down and you will see **How testers join your test** at the bottom.
   [image]

After that testers should accept the inventation, install app from Google Play and check the updates

Comment: If all testers need to use the link to join, do you know what the email list you specify in the testers section is for then? Is it just a safety net so that only users in that list can use the link?

Comment: Users, which aren't in the testers-list can't join to alpha/beta testing. Even if somehow they got a join link.

Comment: For me this link takes to play store on mobile and doesn't work. Should the app be reviewed before internal testing as well?

Comment: you can start closed internal testing [without release](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9845334?hl=en#internal_test) (and review) the application. sometimes it takes too long to get test app in google play. try to clear cache of the google play application and check again later

Answer (score 39):

Here's how I found it (with help from Scar Coder's answer)

1. Log into the Google Play Console and select the app from the list, then click the App releases option in the left sidebar, then click the 'Manage' button for your internal test release:

[image: screenshot showing the manage button]

2. Expand the 'Manage testers area'
3. Copy the Opt-in URL:

[image: screenshot showing opt-in URL location]

Comment: Note this might take some hours to appear, your app has to go from 'Pending publication' to 'Published' first

Comment: Note this also requires **adding the user to any list of testers** first (also visible in the second screenshot).

Answer (score 32):

**You just might have to wait...**

The initial release time of up to 48hrs is what confused me, and is not well communicated on the Play Console:
[image]

Searched for "android Available to internal testers", as Play Console stated exactly this, without the link providing an app (see original question).

Answer (score 8):

App should come to the published status before the Opt-in URL is enabled. You can get your app status in the small '?' symbol or in the drop down box location above the page. Google takes some time to review the app before publish after you submitted it.

Answer (score 4):

On the Play Console, there is an opt-in url that needs to be sent to the internal testers before they can be able to download the app

Comment: Please provide a description of where to find this url, and please also make sure the url is for internal test channel and not alpha or beta channels.

Comment: @RobinManoli this one is tricky :)
Go to the "Internal testing", select the "Testers" tab and on the bottom of the page you'll find "How testers join your test" section. There you can find "Copy link" link, which does the job.
This may come in late, but it can help someone...

Answer (score 1):

As per the new Google Play console, you can share your app to internal testers by visiting [internal app sharing](https://play.google.com/console/u/0/internal-app-sharing) upload page, Upload a new appBundle and share the link.

You can manage your internal testers under internal testing in the play console.

> With internal app sharing, you can quickly share an app bundle or APK with your internal team and testers by uploading an app bundle or APK on the internal app sharing upload page and generating a link. When sharing your app this way, you can restrict access to email lists only or allow anyone whom you share the link with to download.

[Source](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9844679?hl=en#zippy=%2Cupload-and-share-apps-for-testing%2Cuser-isnt-an-internal-app-sharing-tester)

Answer (score 1):

We had to test migration from older app versions to the one under development.
Unfortunately the link to the older version:

```
https://play.google.com/apps/test/<path.to.my.app>/<version code>
```

did not install the old version but the most recent version from the store. Even though the account was registered as "Tester" in "Internal Testing" in the Google Play Console and the developer feature "Internal app sharing" was turned on in the Playstore settings on the tester smartphone.

My solution was to clear the cache of the Google Playstore app.
Then, I had to become a developer in the Playstore again (by tapping "Settings / About / Play Store Version" several times) in order to activate "Settings/General/Internal app sharing" again.

Afterwards, clicking the link worked fine. And I got the longed-for message "This version of this app () may be old. Turn off auto-update for this app to keep it from getting updated." and could perform my tests.

Comment: On my system, the shareable link generated in the Google Play Console is incorrect.  Where it says /test/ it should be /testing/ so I manually edit the URL before sending it out.  Apart from that, your answer helped me.

Answer (score 1):

it is 2023/2024
just click this and open it on your phone.

[image]

Comment: there is no such button anymore

Comment: It's not a button. It's a link and can be found at the end of the Testers page in the Google Play console.

Answer (score 0):

**https://play.google.com/apps/publish --> Select app --> Testing(in Release Part) --> Internal testing --> Testers and scroll Down and in How testers join your part take link of your app by clicking copy link part**

You should visit the link on an Android device