# Can you launch a closed beta before publishing the app?

Tags: android, testing, beta

I want to test my app before fully releasing it but with both the internal testing and the beta testing, Google tells me that I have to release it first. How can I test it a bit before publishing it? Is it possible? 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you don't have to release app to playstore for alpha/beta testing. It is accessible for declared tester (via email) or user accepted beta testing for app.
Probably duplicate. [More Detail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20984120/need-some-clarification-about-beta-alpha-testing-on-the-developer-consol)

Google doc :: [Click here](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213)

Comment: Thanks a lot, for some reason my invitation link wasn't working :)

Comment: Still you are facing that issue@invitation link?? You can check may link for invitation https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52664892/where-do-internal-testers-download-google-play-android-apps/52665005#52665005

Answer (score 1):

No, You do not need to release apk, You upload the apk in alpha or beta testing and it can   only accessible by beta group available to people who are invited via email. You can add emails manually, or upload a CSV file.