# How are internal testers supposed to download Android app?

Tags: android, google-play-console

I'm using the new Google Beta Console (not classic). Here's what I see:

[image]

I added my own email as a tester. Haven't received any email. How should I go about downloading the app to test it? It says "Available to internal testers".

I also noticed that in the Track Summary it says "Inactive"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where do Internal testers download Google Play Android apps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52664892/where-do-internal-testers-download-google-play-android-apps)

Comment: Unfortunately I went to that link and my app is not there.  https://play.google.com/apps/testing/com.cgr